# Compare data from iphone with MYSQL database

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c, iphone

I'm not sure about the best way to solve my problem and wanted to know if you have any ideas/best practices.

I connected my app to MYSQL and I'm able (via .php files) to download and upload certain strings etc.
Now I want to compare the user's contacts (the phone numbers) with the "registered" phone numbers, which are already in the mysql database. When the phone numbers are identical this information should be returned.

I'm thankful for every help!

Best regards
Sebastian

Comment: you need to post your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and easy way to send the phone number to **via.php** which should have following code to check phone number exists or not in database.

```
   $dbConn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
   $phone_num = $_POST['phone_num']; // catch user's phone number via POST ( or you can use GET too )
   $query = "SELECT id FROM tbl_name WHERE phone_num = ?";
   $smt = $dbConn->prepare($query);
   $smt->bindParam(1, $phone_num );
   $smt->execute();
   if($smt->rowCount()){
     echo "Found"; // phone number found!
   }
   else {
     echo "Not found";  // no match found!!
   }
?>
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: sorry for not posting my code in the first place. in order to do that u need to combine download and upload method within Xcode to a) upload the phone_num for the get method and b) to get the answer of the query, right? Is that even possible?